Convert python plotly timeseries line chart to category by day
I have a timeseries data set covering 10 days of upload and download speed measurements. I've created a plotly line chart for the data with one single line each for upload and download over all 10 days. I would rather categorize the chart by day (i.e., 20 lines sharing an x-axis for time of day).
The similar questions I've found so far don't match up with how my data are organized.
I'm currently using the following code...
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
    import plotly.express as px
    from datetime import datetime

...

    # timestamp is a datetime object
    # download_mbps and upload_mbps are floats

    df_prep = []
    for data_object in data_objects:
        df_prep.append({
            "timestamp": data_object.timestamp,
            "date": data_object.timestamp.date(),
            "time": data_object.timestamp.time(),
            "download_mbps": download_mbps,
            "upload_mbps": upload_mbps,
        })

    df = pd.DataFrame(df_prep)

    fig = px.line(df, y=['download_mbps', 'upload_mbps'])
    fig.show()



Can you, please, attach a minimally reproducible example of the code, the graph you are getting with the code above and some drawing (even paint will suffice) of what you want to obtain (without illustrations it is not clear for me from the text)

It sounds like you want to create a Plotly line chart where each day's upload and download speeds are represented as separate lines on the same graph. This way, you'll end up with 20 lines total: one for each day’s upload and download speeds.
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from datetime import datetime

# Assuming you have your data in data_objects
df_prep = []
for data_object in data_objects:
    df_prep.append({
        "timestamp": data_object.timestamp,
        "date": data_object.timestamp.date(),
        "time": data_object.timestamp.time(),
        "download_mbps": data_object.download_mbps,  # Assuming you meant data_object.download_mbps
        "upload_mbps": data_object.upload_mbps,      # Assuming you meant data_object.upload_mbps
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(df_prep)

# Create a new column for time of day to use as x-axis
df['time_of_day'] = df['timestamp'].dt.time

# Melt the DataFrame to have a single 'speed' column and a 'type' column (download/upload)
df_melted = df.melt(id_vars=['date', 'time_of_day'], value_vars=['download_mbps', 'upload_mbps'],
                    var_name='type', value_name='speed')

# Plot with Plotly Express, color by 'date' and line type by 'type'
fig = px.line(df_melted, x='time_of_day', y='speed', color='date', line_dash='type',
              labels={'speed': 'Speed (Mbps)', 'time_of_day': 'Time of Day'},
              title='Upload and Download Speeds by Day')

fig.show()


This doesn't work for me. My x-axis has the times of day for all days rather than just one day's worth of times. It does have the expected number of lines, but they are displayed consecutively rather than all on a common range of x-values (which makes sense given the x-axis being for multiple days).
